# Form submit says Unkown Action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to create a form that submits to a certain action within the current controller (results_controller).

My form code is:

```
 <%= form_tag(:controller => "results", :action => "filter", :id => "filter") do %>
```

And in the results_controlle.rb i have :

```
def filter
      #setting dispatches
        @dispatches = Dispatch.find_by_message_ids(params[:message_ids]) unless params[:message_ids].blank?

      unless @dispatches.blank? || @input_messages.blank?
        @output_messages = OutputMessage.find_by_dispatch_ids(
                                            @dispatches.collect{|d| d.id }.uniq
                                          )
        end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html #default rendering
      end
  end
```

Yet i get the error:

```
Unknown action

The action 'filter' could not be found for ResultsController
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
On the same page, i have a form that does work:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "results", :action => "show", :id => "show")  do %>
```

Comment: Please post your config/routes.rb file.

Comment: @Gazler when i run `rake routes` i get : `/results/show(.:format)       {:controller=>"results", :action=>"show"}` and 

      `results_filter        /results/filter(.:format)     {:controller=>"results", :action=>"filter"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try instead

```
<% form_tag(filter_result_path(), :method => :get) do %>
```

and add to your route table

```
resources :results do
  member do
   get 'filter'
 end
end
```